# MySQL remove images from tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database which contains pages of my website. All of the entries in the table are in html format. All I want to do is to remove `<img ... >` (images) from the content.

Examples of code that I want to remove:

```
<img src="/assets/cache/pic/1052add1887d7066f2ed4546cdd1fff0.pageCache.jpg" alt="" title="" class="left">
<img src="res/images/upload/2011/accident-mortal.jpg" alt="" title="" class="middle">
<img src="res/images/upload/2011/evacuare-strada-orizontului.jpg" alt="" title="" class="middle">
```

Is there a SQL command to do that?

Comment: Your best bet might be to write a small application that uses a DOM parser to query the database, process the strings, and save back to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working. I've used this PHP code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish'") or die(mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $content = $row['post_content'];
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content); 
    $content = addslashes($content);
    $id = $row['ID'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content='".$content."' WHERE ID='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());  

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do substantial text processing with a SQL command seems like a bad idea to me.

But even if it isn't, trying to parse HTML in SQL is surely a terrible idea. (You can get close with a regexp, but you will never catch all the corner cases in finding elements in HTML unless you use a parser.)

I would say that even if this is possible, it is surely not a good way to do it. You will have a terrible time debugging problems and performance will likely be poor to boot.

Either have your application strip out the `<img>` tags before you put the HTML in the database, or have it strip them out after retrieving them from the database.

Comment: Trott the pages are from Wordpress and they represent my posts content. Some of them have images in it and I need to remove them. I have about 25k articles so doing it manually is not an option.

Comment: Who said anything about doing it manually? Just write a program to do it. Don't try to do it inside of SQL itself.

Comment: Well, this is my problem. I don't know how to do that :) Even if I retrieve the fields using PHP, I don't know how to eliminate the images only.

Comment: If you're using PHP, you might have luck with the DOM library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php